# Store/insert XML in JSON field datatype Mariadb

Tags: json, xml, mariadb

I am trying to store all the user data in JSON format in MariaDB. Sometimes few fields have XML data which need to be stored but while storing XML data in JSON I am getting an error. Please help me with how may I store data in JSON

Example:

```
create table temp ( `responseJson` json);

insert into temp value('{"type": "Aadhaar Front Bottom","details":{"qr": {"value": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <PrintLetterBarcodeData uid=\"975876072\" name=\"Akshay ZXY\" gender=\"M\" yob=\"1963\""}}}');
```

But I a getting an error while inserting the above value.

```
 ERROR 4025 (23000): CONSTRAINT `temp.responseJson` failed for `marketplace`.`temp`
```

Please help

Comment: Try double-escaping: `\\"1.0\\"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MariaDB converts a backslash followed by a double quote to a double quote:

```
SELECT '{"key" : "val\"ue"}';
+--------------------+
| {"key" : "val"ue"} |
+--------------------+
| {"key" : "val"ue"} |
+--------------------+
```

`{"key" : "val"ue"}` is not a valid json string (as you can check with JSON_VALID()), since json requires a backslash before the enclosed double quote. So either use `\\"` instead of `\"` or use JSON_QUOTE.:

```
SELECT json_valid('{"key" : "val\"ue"}') AS error, 
       json_valid('{"key" : "val\\"ue"}') AS ok;
+-------+------+
| error | ok   |
+-------+------+
|     0 |    1 |
+-------+------+
```